# Pigeon hole principle question with square area

Tags: combinatorics

A square one inch wide and one inch in length can be cut into 3 equal parts. Show that there is one of the three parts which contains 2 points at a distance of a least one.

I know the square has an area of one. So if you have 2 points by the pigeon the two point go in one square .

But if it is cut into three part each triangle will be 1/2 in length and wide 1/2 and have a distance of $\sqrt\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Ask yourself: In which of the three parts are the corners of the square?

Comment: but how can a square be three equal parts i can see 4 equal parts but not 3

Comment: Divide the square by vertical lines? That's one possibility for congruent pieces. There are plenty of options for pieces of equal area.

Comment: I see so width of my square is one but the lenght is one third

Comment: http://imgur.com/j5V0mA5

Answer (score 1):

At least one of the pieces will contain at least 2 of the corners of the square.